# Order two arrays using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift, core-data

The problem is the follow:

I have two arrays, one with objects, the second with CoreData entities sorted by ids:

```
var objects  = [["id":5],["id":1],["id":3]]
var entities = [["id":1],["id":3],["id":5]]
```

I need to sort the entities in the same order as the objects.
* the entities aim saved yet

I can do it through a loop in a loop, and creating a third array but it is slow and use more memory than it should (My arrays will handle more than 100 entities sometimes)

```
let count = objects.count
var finalArray = []()
for i in 0..<count {
    let id = objects[i].id
    for k in 0..<count {
        if entities[k].id == id {
            finalArray += [entities[k]]
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The code above does work, but it doesn't smells good enough. Any suggestion how to use a build-in Swift more optimal solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a Swift question. It's an algorithm question.  You'd do it the same way in any language.

First, build a map from id to entity. Then, use the map to look up the entities efficiently.

```
var entityForId = [Int:MyEntity]()
for entity in entities {
    entityForId[entity.id] = entity
}

var finalArray = [MyEntity]()
for object in objects {
    if let entity = entityForId[object.id] {
        finalArray.append(entity)
    }
}
```

You can replace the second loop with a single line:

```
var finalArray = objects.flatMap({ entityForId[$0.id] })
```

I find the use of `flatMap` makes the code clearer here, but if you're not familiar with it, you might prefer the explicit loop.

Comment: Thank you Rob, much less cycles now! indeed is an algorithm question, I hopped for a build in "sort compare" on Swift but still, your solution made it optimised enough.